# buffer overflow when copying 4 bytes to a float

Tags: c, memcpy, buffer-overflow

I copy the following 4 bytes: `0x40, 0x7E, 0xA7, 0xF2` to a `float` variable using `memcpy`. Now my c compiler reserves 4 bytes for a `float`, so the 4 bytes I copy into it should not cause overflow.

My output for "Current" is *-2147483648-2147483648.-2147483648 mA*.

The value *-2147483648* seems to suggest buffer overflow. I am not sure why it gives me this value. Here is a compiled example:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  float     current;
} hart_value_t;
hart_value_t  hart_values;

unsigned char buf[4] = { 0x40, 0x7E, 0xA7, 0xF2 };

void spltfp(double value, int * intpart, int * decpart)
{
  int i;
  double dec;

  i = (int)value;
  printf("What value do I get here: %d", i);
  dec = value - i;

  if (dec < 0) {
    dec = -dec;
  }

  *intpart = i;
  *decpart = (int)(dec * 100);
}

void hartBufferReadFloat(unsigned char * buf, float * data)
{
  printf("What is the size of float: %lu", sizeof(float)); // returns 4
  memcpy(data, buf, 4); /* 0x40, 0x7E, 0xA7, 0xF2 */
}

void hartPrintFloat(float val)
{
  int intpart, decpart;

  spltfp(val, &intpart, &decpart);
  printf("%d.%02d", intpart, decpart);
}

int main(void)
{
    hartBufferReadFloat(buf, &hart_values.current);
    printf("Current: "); hartPrintFloat(hart_values.current); printf(" mA\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it lacks some code: where is the definition of buf, hartvalues and so on? Please post a complete, minimal working code if you can

Comment: @JohnMerlino what is the value that is printed if you just print the data right after the memcpy?

Comment: @prmottajr the value I get after memcpy is -6635087811186044596524171657216.000000

Comment: I edited it so it can compile own its own now.

Comment: Note: Better to use `printf("What is the size of float: %zu", sizeof(float));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the values, 0x40, 0x7e, 0xa7, 0xf2, in the order for a big-endian system, but your system is little-endian. They need to be reversed.

Directly accessing the bytes that represent objects is generally not portable between different systems. The order in which bytes appear in the representation is just one of the differences that may occur.

Answer (score -1):

The float has it own format, where not all int-like 32 bit values are valid. Check [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: This is not relevant; the OP is not attempting to copy the bytes of an `int` into a `float` object. They are trying to copy the values of bytes that encode a `float` into a `float` object. The bytes are already encoded correctly (except that they are in the wrong order).

Comment: Why downvote? I just assumed that this value represents some NaN, quite or signalling Nan (Not a Number)... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN, which could be the case given no endianess specified...

Comment: The assumption you state is incorrect. The bytes of the float, in the wrong order, represent 6635087811186044596524171657216, not a NaN. In the right order, they represent about 3.97900, which is a suitable value for a number of milliamps. It is quite clear the problem was an incorrect ordering of bytes, not some `int`/`float` confusion. The code is clearly not expecting “all int-like 32 bit values” to be valid; it is attempting to reconstruct a particular `float` from previously ascertained values of the bytes representing it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I should have checked the values for valid float, the OP hardcoded the values into char array... BTW which is strange, given OP is displaying or using mA/current value, with single precision... :) Anyway you are right

Comment: I expect the values listed on the question are just one sample. The use of a buffer suggests the values are being obtained from elsewhere, such as a file or a network message containing bytes written previously.